# Why Use a Constructor Twice In Java

Tags: java, oop

I am brand new to Java. I have pretty good experience with OOP, but this kinda just strikes me as odd. I am reading the book `Think Java, How to Think Like a Computer Scientist`. It is going over Constructors and how to use them. Anyhow, let me get to the point. This is the code:

```
class Time {
    int hour, minute;
    double second;

    public Time() {
        this.hour = 0;
        this.minute = 0;
        this.second = 0.0;
    }

    public Time(int hour, int minute, double second) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // one way to create and initialize a Time object Time
        t1 = new Time();
        t1.hour = 11;
        t1.minute = 8;
        t1.second = 3.14159;
        System.out.println(t1);

        // another way to do the same thing Time
        t2 = new Time(11, 8, 3.14159); System.out.println(t2);
    }
}
```

My question deals specifically with this:

```
    public Time() {
        this.hour = 0;
        this.minute = 0;
        this.second = 0.0;
    }

    public Time(int hour, int minute, double second) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }
```

I am very confused on why that is written that way. Why do that? Couldn't this be written just as simply as the following(?):

```
    public Time() {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }
```

---

Why would I go through all of the extra trouble of writing it the long way? Or is that the correct way of going about it? Could someone please better explain this to me, Thank You! :)

Comment: One is a no-arg ctor. One takes args. They're different and do different things. What happened when you tried what your wanted to do?

Comment: Perhaps a better way to have written this would be for the no-arg constructor to call the arg constructor, using `this(0,0,0.0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below, the usual constructor is to initialize the instance variables.  Each line of the constructor initializes an instance variable to an arbitrary default primitive value(in this case, midnight). The constructor doesn't take any arguments due to the empty parentheses (). You can use this the same way you use the name of any other object. For example, you can read and write the instance variables of this, and you can pass this as an argument to other methods.But you do not declare this and you do not use new to create it. In fact, you are not even allowed to make an assignment to it! this is created by the system; all you have to do is store values in its instance variables.

```
public Time() {
    this.hour = 0;
    this.minute = 0;
    this.second = 0.0;  
}
```

The below constructor that is overloaded, just like any other methods, which means you can provide multiple constructors with different parameters. And java know which constructor to invoke by matching the arguments of the new command with the parameters of the constructors.

It's very common to have one constructor that takes no arguments and one constructor that takes a parameter list that is identical to the list of instances variables. The names and types of the parameters are exactly the same as the names and types of the instance variables. All the constructor does is copy the information from the parameters to the instance variables.

Note that overloading constructors provides the flexibility to create an object first and then fill in the blank, or to collect all the information before creating the object.

```
public Time(int hour, int minute, double second) {
 // this.hour, this.minute, this.second are instances variables
               this.hour = hour;
               this.minute = minute;
               this.second = second;
 }
```

**When Create a New Object:**
   Although constructors look like methods, you never invoke them directly. Instead, when you use the new command, the system allocates space for the new object and then invokes your constructor to initialize the instance variables.

In main, the first time we invoke the new command, we provide no arguments, so Java invokes the first constructor. The next few lines assign values to each of the instance variables.

```
// one way to create and initialize a Time object
 Time t1 = new Time ();
 t1.hour = 11;
 t1.minute = 8;
 t1.second = 3.14159;
 System.out.println (t1);
```

The second time we invoke the new command, we provide arguments that match the parameters of the second constructor. This way of initializing the instance variables is more concise (and slightly more efficient), but it can be harder to read, since it is not as clear which value are assigned to which instance variables.

```
// another way to do the same thing
 Time t2 = new Time (11, 8, 3.14159);
 System.out.println (t2);
```

Comment: Wow Thank You. Best answer so far, and it explains it 100x better! :) Thank You again, very helpful, and I think I actually pretty much understand it now! :D

Answer (score 1):

No, because your suggested alternative of

```
public Time() {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
}
```

Doesn't pass in `hour`, `minute` or `second`. As a consequence, it would be equivalent to

```
public Time() {
    this.hour = this.hour;
    this.minute = this.minute;
    this.second = this.second;
}
```

Which would make every field `0`.

Comment: Hmm, that does make much more sense. Thank You! :)

Comment: Hello, @Emz, I hate to be rude but you know I have to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer right? You never even gave me a chance :)

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, they might disappear at any time.

Answer (score 1):

The first example creates two constructors, providing two separate ways to construct the object. The first, provided no arguments, gives a default time value. The second takes the current hour, minute, and second and constructs a time object based on the arguments. Your suggested shortening would not do anything of use. The assignments in your single constructor would be trivial and still assign all of the variables to zero.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are assigning the values to themselves:

```
public Time() {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
}
```

To remove your confusion, actually in its current form this constructor:

```
public Time() {
     this.hour = 0;
    this.minute = 0;
    this.second = 0.0;
}
```

is adding no value because it is initialising the fields with their default values. And instance variables are already initiated to their default values on object creation.

But if the default values are different then it makes sense to add such a constructor, for example:

```
public Time() {
    this.hour = -1;
    this.minute = -2;
    this.second = 5.0; // random defaults chosen
}
```

Comment: Actually the no-arg constructor is required if you want to create a Time object with the default field values, but the body of the constructor given does nothing.  The default no-arg constructor only exists if no other constructor is written.

Comment: @CarlManaster I know but don't confuse the default constructor with no-args constructor.

Comment: Hello, @Juned that makes more sense thank you. Now I hate to hassle, but could you please explain the difference between the two constructers, the one with and without params. I am still just a bit a confused.

Comment: @MichaelJones without param is setting values to some hard default values, whereas the argument constructor initialises them with dynamic argument values.

Comment: Oooh! :) Thank You, that makes so much more sense

Answer (score 0):

This is the class definition:

```
class Time {
    int hour, minute;
    double second;

    public Time() {
        this.hour = 0;
        this.minute = 0;
        this.second = 0.0;
    }

    public Time(int hour, int minute, double second) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // one way to create and initialize a Time object Time
        t1 = new Time();
        t1.hour = 11;
        t1.minute = 8;
        t1.second = 3.14159;
        System.out.println(t1);

        // another way to do the same thing Time
        t2 = new Time(11, 8, 3.14159); System.out.println(t2);
    }
}
```

But remember that a class can have different instances, if you create a new object linke the follow:

```
Time t=new Time();
```

In this object you are going to have 0,0,0.0.

But in another object created using the other constructor:

```
Time t=new Time(1,1,1.1);
```

You are going to initialize the object in a different way, and this is one of the benefits to use more than one constructor.

I hope I can help you

Answer (score 0):

The rationale is simple:  someone would like an alternative way to create a new instance of `Time`.  However, since the values for hour, minute or second aren't implicitly known, it is instantiated with default values.

You can't do what you're suggesting, because as others have pointed out, it's equivalent to assigning the value to itself.  However, it would have the same effect, since the [default value of an int field is 0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).  The main problem here is that it is difficult to read.

Most use cases of this pattern that I've seen make use of the `this` keyword so that such an assignment only occurs once, and self-assignments are less likely to occur.

```
public Time() {
   this(0, 0, 0);
}
```

In other cases, if you wanted to do this sort of thing with the constructor, you could set default values to any other parameters you wanted, and pass in the one you care about.  For example, an offset with hours would look something like this:

```
public Time(int hour) {
    this(hour, 0, 0);
}
```

...and you only need to write the actual assignment of those values **once**.

```
public Time(int hour, int minute, double second) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
}
```